# Very interesting multivariable calculus question.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

If $\displaystyle z = \frac{f(x-y)}{y}$, show that $\displaystyle z + y \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$.

Comment: That is clever...but what are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= \frac{f'(x-y)}{y}, \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{-f'(x-y)y - f(x-y)}{y^2} = -\frac{f'(x-y)}{y} - \frac{f(x-y)}{y^2}. 
$$

So:
$$
z + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{f(x-y)}{y} + y\cdot \frac{f'(x-y)}{y} - f'(x-y) - \frac{f(x-y)}{y} = 0.
$$

Comment: we have to take partial derivative.

Comment: @user114873: my notation dz/dx means partial derivative of z w.r.t x

Comment: Why not use $\LaTeX$?

Comment: @OJB: I will edit it in mathjax a little later.